# Is it possible to place an external dart page in to the sliding_up_panel 0.3.5?

Tags: flutter, dart, implementation, slidingpanelayout

I want to build a simple app with a slide up panel, in this slide up panel there should be a chat with a chat bot, I have written a working chatbot app in flutter and a working app with a slide up panel, but now I don't really know how to get the chat into the slide up panel... 
Therefore it would be easiest if I could simply implement the other dart file into the slide up panel.

So far I have tried to integrate the app eineld into each other, but fail every time...

Code of the functioning Slide up panel app (main.dart)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


void main() => runApp(SlidingUpPanelExample());

class SlidingUpPanelExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.black,
    ));

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'MS AI',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final double _initFabHeight = 120.0;
  double _fabHeight;
  double _panelHeightOpen = 575.0;
  double _panelHeightClosed = 95.0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    _fabHeight = _initFabHeight;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[

          SlidingUpPanel(
            maxHeight: _panelHeightOpen,
            minHeight: _panelHeightClosed,
            parallaxEnabled: true,
            parallaxOffset: .5,
            body: _body(),
            panel: _panel(),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0), topRight: Radius.circular(18.0)),
            onPanelSlide: (double pos) => setState((){
              _fabHeight = pos * (_panelHeightOpen - _panelHeightClosed) + _initFabHeight;
            }),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 42.0,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 18.0, 24.0, 18.0),
              child: Text(
                "AI",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .25),
                    blurRadius: 16.0
                )],
              ),
            ),
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _panel(){
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),

        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 30,
              height: 5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 18.0,),

        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Chat",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                fontSize: 24.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 36.0,),

        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[


    Text("This is where the chat should go", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,)),
            ],
          ),
        ),


      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _button(String label, IconData icon, Color color){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
                blurRadius: 8.0,
              )]
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),

        Text(label),
      ],

    );
  }

  Widget _body(){
  }
}
```

Code of the working chat bot app (chat.dart)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dialogflow/dialogflow_v2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.black,
    ));

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MS-AI',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new HomePageDialogflow(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePageDialogflow extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePageDialogflow({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageDialogflow createState() => new _HomePageDialogflow();
}

class _HomePageDialogflow extends State<HomePageDialogflow> {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return new IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                decoration:
                new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Send a message"),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void response(query) async {
    _textController.clear();
    AuthGoogle authGoogle =
    await AuthGoogle(fileJson: "assets/credentials.json")
        .build();
    Dialogflow dialogflow =
    Dialogflow(authGoogle: authGoogle, language: Language.english);
    AIResponse response = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
    ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
      text: response.getMessage() ??
          new CardDialogflow(response.getListMessage()[0]).title,
      name: "AI",
      type: false,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) {
    _textController.clear();
    ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
      text: text,
      name: "User",
      type: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    response(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: new Text("MS-AI"),
      ),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
              itemCount: _messages.length,
            )),
        new Divider(height: 1.0),
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
          child: _buildTextComposer(),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.text, this.name, this.type});

  final String text;
  final String name;
  final bool type;

  List<Widget> otherMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text('AI')),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(this.name,
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> myMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      new Expanded(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(this.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: new CircleAvatar(
            child: new Text(
              this.name[0],
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: this.type ? myMessage(context) : otherMessage(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.